# Compute date averages

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to make a query that shows me the daily, half-year, and monthly averages - in MySQL or SQL. The dates are in the Unix format, but they also have been converted into standard format as shown below.

I have the following table (fecha unix - Unix date, fecha normal - regular date, Nombre - name):

```
Nombre          | fecha unix| fecha normal          |value  |
JOHANNA ANDREA  |1273533527 |2010-05-10 19:18:47    |1.2    |
ANA MARIA       |1273533572 |2010-05-10 19:19:32    |2.0    |
CARLOS MANUEL   |1273542938 |2010-05-10 21:55:38    |2.0    |
LEONARDO ANGEL  |1273543988 |2010-05-10 22:13:08    |1.6    |
PATRICIO HERNAN |1273546656 |2010-05-10 22:57:36    |1.8    |
LILIAN CECILIA  |1273585499 |2010-05-11 09:44:59    |2.0    |
ROSA MERCEDES   |1273590042 |2010-05-11 11:00:42    |1.8    |
GABRIEL TORO    |1461837600 |2016-04-28 07:00:00    |1.2    |
FELIPE RUIZ     |1461837680 |2016-04-28 07:01:20    |1.6    |
CARLOS TAPIA    |1461847680 |2016-04-28 09:48:00    |1.8    |
```

Expected result for the day:

```
fecha       | value
2010-05-10  | 1.7
2010-05-11  | 1.9
2016-04-28  | 1.5
```

for the month:

```
2010-05 | 1.7
2010-04 | 1.5
```

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Por favor, haga su pregunta en [es.stackoverflow.com](http://es.stackoverflow.com/) o aquí pero en inglés.

Comment: The question was made in spanish.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by date like so

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME('fecha unix')) AS fecha,
        AVERAGE(*) AS Average
 FROM   MyPostsTable
 GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME('fecha unix')
 ORDER BY fecha
```

By month like so

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME('fecha unix')) AS fecha,
            AVERAGE(Value) AS Average
     FROM   MyPostsTable
     GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME('fecha unix'))
     ORDER BY fecha;
```

And I think by week like so

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME('fecha unix')) AS fecha,
                AVERAGE(Value) AS Average
         FROM   MyPostsTable
         GROUP BY WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME('fecha unix'))
         ORDER BY fecha;
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning - untested, syntax errors possible, but hopefully you get the idea.

By day:

```
select date_format(fecha_normal, '%Y-%m-%d') fecha, avg(Value) from tbl group by 1
```

By month:

```
select date_format(fecha_normal, '%Y-%m') fecha, avg(Value) 
  from tbl group by 1
```

By half-year:

```
select concat(year(fecha_normal), '-', 
  if(month(fetcha_normal) < 7, 1, 2)) fecha, avg(Value) 
  from tbl group by 1
```

The idea here is that we use special formatting combined with SQL function logic (if) to construct year-1 string for the first half of the year, and year-2 for the second.

By year:

```
select year(fecha_normal) fecha, avg(Value) from tbl group by 1
```